# Margin White Stripe

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble getting rid of what it appears to be a margin error?...i've already tried setting margin and padding values as 0 but i keep getting that line, should i downsize the video or something?

I inserted the background video on a div tag. Is the video just out of place?

[image: White line on the left]

```css
    /* Default to hide the video on all devices */
#video{display:none}

/* Default to display the image on all devices */
#videosubstitute{display:block;width:auto;height:100%;}


html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}


/*START VIDEO
==================================================*/
#fullScreenDiv{
    width:100vh;
    min-height: 100vh; 
   /* Set the height to match that of the viewport. */
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    padding:0!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;

}
#video{    
    width: 100vw; 
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    volume: .02;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video{
    height: 150%;
    top: -100%;
  }
  #videosubstitute{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;}
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #video {
    width: 150%;
    left: -100%;
  }
  #videosubstitute{display:block;width:auto;height:100%;}
}
/*if there is 992  pixels or more, then display the video but hide the image*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
#video{display:block;}
#videosubstitute{display:none}
}   

/* The container for our text and stuff */
#messageBox{
    position: absolute;  top: 0;  left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

/*END VIDEO
==================================================*/
```

```html
<div id="fullScreenDiv" class="table-cell">

            <img src="https://www.imi21.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/t12.jpg" id="videosubstitute" alt="Full screen background video"></img>

        <div id="videoDiv">           
            <video preload="preload" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
            <!-- Note: Replacing the following sources that are local:
            <source src="img/mc10.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
            <source src="img/mc10.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> -->
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
            </video>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind putting together a runnable demo?

Comment: Your demo seems to be working more or less. The screen goes dark when I upsize the window, but with a small window the `fill: contain` works as expected and without any border or margin.

Comment: With missing properties like `class="table-cell"` I have a feeling there's more going on than what you are showing.

Comment: Running the code snippet and clicking "Full Page" does not show the white space problem you have screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems off:

```
width:100vh;
```

`vh` means percent of the screen height. Probably a bad idea to use that as width.

Are you really sure you want the video to be cut off at the sides of the screen? Wouldn't it be better to have a black background and let the video fill the available space without stretching? E.g. `fill: contain`

Comment: If you need clarification from the questioner, you need to ask it in the comments under the question. Do not place questions in the Answer section.

Comment: @Rob it isn't a question, but more of a suggestion in question form.